# nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument ubuntu 16.04 xenial

Tags: python, django, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I know this is a known bug, but i dont know how to resolve that because i do lot of googling and after that finally back to stack to get some real solution :

Here are configuration:

First i install nginx by:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx

lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04

apt-cache policy nginx-core
nginx-core:
  Installed: 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://sg.mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://sg.mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg

/status
     1.9.15-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://sg.mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

My nginx service config is like:

```
nano /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service

# Stop dance for nginx
# =======================
#
# ExecStop sends SIGSTOP (graceful stop) to the nginx process.
# If, after 5s (--retry QUIT/5) nginx is still running, systemd takes control
# and sends SIGTERM (fast shutdown) to the main process.
# After another 5s (TimeoutStopSec=5), and if nginx is alive, systemd sends
# SIGKILL to all the remaining processes in the process group (KillMode=mixed).
#
# nginx signals reference doc:
# http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html
#
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My nginx.conf file is like:
     nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##
 tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
  ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
# gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
```

When i start nginx server i get 502 error on my web page and status of the nginx is:

```
 sudo service nginx status
sudo: unable to resolve host iZt4ndf6hh48rtirr7qry9Z
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-10-15 16:34:10 CST; 4h 42min ago
  Process: 2682 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2703 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2700 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2706 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2706 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           └─2707 nginx: worker process

Oct 15 16:34:10 iZt4ndf6hh48rtirr7qry9Z systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 15 16:34:10 iZt4ndf6hh48rtirr7qry9Z systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Oct 15 16:34:10 iZt4ndf6hh48rtirr7qry9Z systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Now i search on google and find that pid bug but i try to resolve that error but i am unable to do so.

Thanks for reading and your precious time.

Comment: The `nginx.service` came with installation or you added it yourself manually? Because the file contents are incorrect

Comment: it comes with `nginx.service`. and what is incorrect there...

Comment: See if the sleep solution mentioned in this link helps https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864

Comment: Let me try i will let you know. Thanks for you response.

Comment: Now its working fine ...thanks for the response

Answer (score 8):

This happens due to a race condition as discussed in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864.

As documented the workaround is to run below to create a override file

```
printf "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n" > /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start nginx
```